# Edziga formulo en Esperanto

Tags: culture

Mi supozas, ke pro Edzperanto jam estis nuptoj en Esperanto. Kion oni diras?

Mi trovis fragmenton en artikolo de monato:

> ...ami, estimi kaj honori, dum ĉiuj tagoj de mia vivo, en bonaj kaj malbonaj tagoj, en sano kaj malsano, ĝis la morto nin disigos.

Kaj jen kion mi trovis laŭ la sep sakramentoj:

> Nupto-Promeso:
>
> N., antaŭ la vizaĝo de Dio mi akceptas vin kiel mian edz[in]on.
>
> Mi promesas al vi fidelecon en bonaj kaj malbonaj tagoj, en sano kaj
>   malsano, ĝis la morto nin separos.
>
> Mi volas ami vin, estimi kaj honori, dum ĉiuj tagoj de mia vivo.
>
> Portu tiun ĉi ringon kiel signon de nia amo kaj fideleco:
>
> En la nomo de la Patro kaj de la Filo kaj de la Sankta Spirito.

Mi ŝatus scii, ĉu oni vere uzas ilin. Eblas, ke estas aliaj vortigoj kaj ke dependas de la devenlandoj de la paro tamen nur tion mi povis trovi.

Comment: Sendube jam (ecx en la pasintaj du jardekoj) okazis ceremonioj en Esperanto. Mi plusendis vian demandon al kelkaj amikoj por vidi cxu iu povos respondi pli konkrete.

Comment: Cxu via demando estas cxu precize tiu cxi ceremonio uzigxis?

Answer (score 1):

Mi metis tiun demandon sur mian personan paĝon en Facebook, kaj mi jam aŭdis de aŭ pri kvin paroj kies geedziĝa ceremonio estis plene aŭ parte en Esperanto.

Mi ankaŭ aŭdis de pastro kiu atentigis ke la himnaro Adoru enhavas kristanan diservon por geedzigi paron. Se iu bezonas Esperantan geedziĝon, mi povas prezenti vin al tiu pastro. :-)

Comment: Bone. Mi scivolas pri la vortoj uzataj. Ĉu ili uzis kion mi skribis supre?

Comment: Gxis nun neniu diris ke jes.